# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly, but can't think of how else

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

I've read a lot of these on here but I can't make head nor tail of them, apologies if this seems a waste of time but I am trying.

I am trying to implement the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm and right now I'm attempting to implement the failure table. I am struggling to assign variables j and i to my length 20 string which I have sliced into steps of 1. I keep getting an error when I attempt to assign j and i to the next part of the string.

```
j + 1
i + 1
```

Is what is giving me the error but I'm unsure how to do this any differently.

I'm new to this game and its been a long day with it apologies if this is extremely vague any help would be appreciated

```
 n = fileContents
 m = random_item
 myList = [0]
 j = m[0]
 i = m[1]
 global failTable


 splitted = m.split()
 step = 1
 [m[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(m), step)]

class myList:
    def __init__(self,m):
        self.pattern = myList
class myList:
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        myList.__init__(self.m)

        print(self.m)
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if [j == i]:
            j + 1
            i + 1
            [myList.append([j + 1])]
        elif [j != i]:
            if [i < m(len)]:
                i + 1
            elif [j < 1]:
                [myList.append([j])]
            elif[j >= 1]:
                [myList.append([myList - 1])]
            elif[i == m(len)]:
                [myList.append([myList - 1])]
        elif [i == m(len) and j == 0 and j != 0]:
            break
```

I know its probably a mess but I'm completely unsure how to code it. I understand the method of what it should be doing but not how to code it.

Again, many thanks and sorry for the mess

Comment: Can you post a longer snippet?

Comment: @BAH I'm a little embarrassed by it because I'm not sure what I'm doing but i'll put it up

Comment: Indeed that is some short snippet ;). The error gives you a hint: it's trying to convert an integer to a string. What is `j` supposed to be and what is `j + 1` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Woody we've all written horrible code at some point, so don't be embarrassed (not implying that your code is horrible btw)

Comment: Regardless of how you feel about the code, we are here to help. And if you want that help, a [mcve] goes a long way

Comment: i appreciate the help guys @cricket_007

Comment: @BAH wouldn't let you in above

Comment: @Woody: You've got a lot of square brackets that shouldn't be there. `if [j == i]` will do totally other things than you think. Do you even know what the square brackets are for?

Comment: @Matthias i didn't until you mentioned just there. Square brackets contents can be changed?

Comment: `i + 1` is giving you an error? What error? What's the value of `i`?

Comment: I'm not even getting that far now @Goyo .

Comment: @Goyo
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/x/untitled.py", line 48, in <module>
    class myList:
  File "/Volumes/x/untitled.py", line 59, in myList
    if i < m(len):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: If that's actually your problem just explain it in the question and I bet you'll get an answer in less than a minute. But it says that `j + 1` and `j + 1` "is what is giving me the error" and the title says something about converting `int` to `str`. Looks like the error is kind of a moving target.

Comment: @Goyo it seems that way, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a string to an int, which is undefined.

You are calling your strings i and j, so I think you intend them to be integer. Modify your code so that's the case.

I would also suggest you first start with a python tutorial. This will save you a lot of time.

In particular, seeing things like

```
if [ i == j ]:
```

is worrying to me, and I think you do not code what you intend to. I think you mean:

```
if i == j:
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Python is a great language, you'll enjoy learning and using it.